# A gap in a proof of Orlov’s result on the group of autoequivalences of the derived category of an abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, derived-categories

Let $X$ be an abelian variety over an algebraically closed field of charactristic $0$. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9712017), Orlov showed that there is a short exact sequence $$0\to \mathbb Z \oplus X \times \hat X \to\operatorname{Auteq}(Perf X) \to Sp(X\times \hat X) \to 0,$$
where $\operatorname{Auteq}(Perf X)$ denotes the group of triangulated autoequivalences and $Sp(X\times \hat X)$ denotes the group of symplectic (or isometric) automorphisms of $X \times \hat X$. In this question [Factorization of symplectic isomorphisms of abelian varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25952/factorization-of-symplectic-isomorphisms-of-abelian-varieties), the person explained $Sp(X\times \hat X)$ and asked how to fill in an argument right after Proposition 4.12 about factorization of any symplectic automorphism into a composition of two symplectic automorphisms whose factors corresponding to maps from $\hat X$ to $X$ are isogenies, which is used to show the surjectivity in the sequence above and is claimed to be easy. Moreover, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00232) addresses the exact issue brought up in the question, mentioning the authors believe the argument is indeed not "easy" unless $X$ is for example simple.

I personally could not fill in this argument either and I am wondering if the argument has been verified elsewhere or known to work out now. I would really appreciate your comments.